# iTunes: making it remember the last song and position

Tags: itunes

I have a big collection of music. I thought it would be so natural to remember the last playlist, the last song (and possibly also the position within the song) that I played before I closed iTunes, e.g. because I restarted the computer. So many applications do this, take XCode for example.

So is there maybe a script, or some kind of a plugin that does this? Or any other way?

Or maybe we should ask Apple to add this simple functionality?

**Update**: iTunes 10.6 remembers the last playlist, but still not the last played song. Well, getting closer each year...

Comment: Recently played PALYLISTS didn't solve your problem?

Comment: @Am1rr3zA: not really. The way I imagine it is I open iTunes and see it in the same state as when I last closed it. I want to be able to continue listening the album or maybe the whole playlist. Doing that through the Last Played is a lot of extra clicks: click Last Played, click the top song, right-click, select "Show in such and such play list", and only then "Play". And btw, "last played" doesn't include tracks that you haven't finished listening to.

Comment: i don't understand why it still *more than eight years after this question* iTunes won't remember _up next_ list when restarting... it shouldn't be that hard Apple :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Relaunch](http://wiredupandfiredup.co.uk/Relaunch/) application: before close iTunes take a snapshot from iTunes with Relaunch and next time, load this snapshot (or set it to auto-load).

Relaunch saves you time by taking Snapshots of which applications you are using, and starts them back up for you. Think of it as a launcher on steroids that lets you switch between work contexts with one click.

You can take a snapshot before restarting your system, and after that double-click on the snapshot you created. Then it restores all your files and applications you had open.

Comment: Relaunch has been discontinued. itd be great if there was another solution, that seemed great.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you're asking for the same functionality as the iPod, which picks up right where you left off when you turn it on. You'd expect the same thing from iTunes. Maybe Apple is trolling the forums and will get the hint.

Comment: Hello ranger rover and welcome to Ask Different! Your response here is more like a 'comment' than 'answer'.  I'm sorry as a new user you don't have privileges yet to post comments (yet!), but until you do please reserve the 'Answer' field for true answers. This makes our question and answer site work as intended.

Comment: Please place this as a comment.